# How to encode a string for url param in python

Tags: python, urlencode

How can I encode a string so that I can pass the encoded string in url params?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use urllib.quote_plus function. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8";
print

import urllib

str = "Hello World?"
str = urllib.quote_plus(str)

print str
```

Output:
    Hello+World%3F

Comment: Python 3: `str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str)`

Answer (score 0):

The library too use is `urllib`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

```
>>> import urllib
>>> f = { 'eventName' : 'myEvent', 'eventDescription' : "cool event"}
>>> urllib.urlencode(f)
'eventName=myEvent&eventDescription=cool+event'

>>> urllib.quote_plus('string_of_characters_like_these:$#@=?%^Q^$')
'string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [urllib.encode()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> f = { 'eventName' : 'myEvent', 'eventDescription' : "cool event"}
>>> urllib.urlencode(f)
'eventName=myEvent&eventDescription=cool+event'
```